# How can I clear defaults from WebApplicationBuilder.CreateBuilder()?

Tags: c#, .net

In a .NET 6 / 7 web project, the default builder is used on the very first line

```
var builder = WebApplicationBuilder.CreateBuilder();
```

And this builder then has configs such as "appsettings.json" and "appsettings.Development.json" included in it.

The documentation says:

> ... initializes a new instance of the WebApplication class with preconfigured defaults

But I don't want those defaults. I'd like to get rid of appsettings and appsettings.development.

I used to be able to do this in lower versions of .NET using the builder.Host with `Clear` or something but now it seems I can only *add* to those default configs? Or do I have to use the older class libraries to get full control of the configs etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clear them out:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.Sources.Clear();
});
```

Comment: Beautiful. And I'd used that options syntax for something else in another project -just hadn't added 1 + 1 together... Thanks! Will accept soon (when it lets me)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://tion-during-startup/69722959#69722959) [`ConfigurationManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) returned by [`WebApplicationBuilder.Configuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder.configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0) property allows to setup the config, you can clear default configuration sources from it:

```cs
builder.Configuration.Sources.Clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting an addition to the answer I accepted because I also came across some problems, since it clears ALL the default configs (so things from launchsettings etc. were disappearing).

You can either remove ALL the configs and re-add them one-by-one if you know what each one is doing and which ones you need e.g.

```
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.Sources.Clear();
});

builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables("DOTNET_");
```

Or if you're unsure what these defaults are actually doing and only want to target specific types of files to remove, just linq filter the specific Json / appsettings type files and use `Remove`

```
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    foreach(var jsonConfigSource in config.Sources.Where(x => x.GetType().Name == "JsonConfigurationSource"))
    {
        config.Sources.Remove(jsonConfigSource);
    }
});
```